# How to Insert and delete rows in chunks using Merge statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Tables Target and Source and I have to perform Insert and delete on Target table by comparing the Source table. I have to do this in chunks as I want to maintain maximum concurrency as multiple threads are using Source and Target table and source Table has 10 Million records. I have two questions -

1. I am scared of using my below code on production. So I want to confirm if my below code is safe to use and will it give performance gain. Both the tables have clustered index on the joining column (ID) and non clustered index on columns - name,v1,v2,v3.

   ```
   declare @i int = 1
   while @i > 0
   begin
   merge top (1000) target as a
   using source as b
   on a.id = b.id    

   when not matched by target then
   insert (id,name,v1,v2,v3)
   values(b.id,b.name,b.v1,b.v2,b.v3)

   when not matched by source then
   delete;
   set @i = @@rowcount
   end
   ```
2. My second question is - I did some search on Merge statement and found out that most of the developers do prefer the old way to insert and delete rows from table that is using separate Insert and delete statements with where exists because Merge results in locking issues. I want to know all the disadvantages of merge statement and reason for locking issues.

Please advise? Thanks.. :)

Comment: Your question is both too broad and primarily opinion based. You might take a look at this article. It covers a broad spectrum of issues with MERGE. Please note, this article is a few years old at this point. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: I use merge for one reason, to perform multiple actions (CRUD) transitionally without being in a transaction. IE, it all works or all fails. There is not speed difference so if you are doing chunks, do whatever you're most comfortable with.